# Python CTypes: Intel Mac v.s. Windows Different Results

Tags: python, c++, dll, dylib

So I am currently interfacing a compiled .dll (Windows side) with a ctypes interface on the Python side. To track progress from within the .dll I pass in a function pointer to a callback function that receives a struct object. This works perfectly fine on Windows.

After compiling the same code on Mac the .dylib perform the entire process the exact same way; however when the callback function receives the struct pointer the values stored inside seem to be completely wrong.

If anyone could provide input I'd greatly appreciate it.

On the Python side the structs are defined as such

```
class ProgressReportC(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("numberOfStages", ctypes.c_int), ("stageEnum", ctypes.c_uint), ("progressPercent", ctypes.c_double),
                ("currentStage", ctypes.c_int), ("currentStageProgress", ctypes.c_int), ("index", ctypes.c_int),
                ("pInstance", ctypes.c_void_p)]

class ReturnStructC(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("exitCode", ctypes.c_int), ("tab", ctypes.c_int)]
```

**Edit**

Below I've detailed a minimal reproducible example
CPP files are compiled as such:

```
clang -arch x86_64 -fno-builtin -dynamiclib -o test.dylib main.cpp
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

void doThing(void (*callback)(struct ProgressReport))
{
    printf("%p\n", callback);
    ProgressReport pr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pr.tab = i;
        pr.currentStage = i;
        pr.currentStageProgress = i;
        pr.numberOfStages = i;
        pr.progressPercent = i;
        pr.stageEnum = i;
        printf("%i\t%i\t\n", pr.tab, pr.currentStage);
        (*callback)(pr);
    }
}
```

**Main.h**

```
struct ProgressReport
{
    int numberOfStages;
    unsigned stageEnum;
    double progressPercent;
    int currentStage;
    int currentStageProgress;
    int tab;
};

extern "C" void doThing(void (*func)(struct ProgressReport) = NULL);
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes
import os
import logging
import sys

class ProgressReportC(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("numberOfStages", ctypes.c_int), ("stageEnum", ctypes.c_uint), ("progressPercent", ctypes.c_double),
                ("currentStage", ctypes.c_int), ("currentStageProgress", ctypes.c_int), ("tab", ctypes.c_int)]

def _status_report(prog):
    prog_pointer = prog.contents
    progress_report = {'tab_num': prog_pointer.tab,
                        'number_of_stages': prog_pointer.numberOfStages ,
                        'current_readable_operation': prog_pointer.currentStage,
                        'current_percent': prog_pointer.progressPercent, 'current_stage': prog_pointer.currentStage,
                        'current_stage_progress': prog_pointer.currentStageProgress}
    print(progress_report)

_callback_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(ProgressReportC))
_status_report_call_back = _callback_type(_status_report)

if sys.platform == "darwin":
    path = os.getcwd()
    polyDll = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(path, "test.dylib"), ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)

_dothing = polyDll['doThing']
_dothing.argtype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(ProgressReportC))
_dothing.restype = None

a = _dothing(_status_report_call_back)
```

**Example Output**

```
{'tab_num': 0, 'number_of_stages': 1297437784, 'current_readable_operation': 0, 'current_percent': 1.77398848124697e-310, 'current_stage': 0, 'current_stage_progress': 1297437784}
These values are printed from inside the .dylib function...
92      92
```

Comment: Are both OS 64-bit?  What does `ctypes.sizeof()` report for each structure on each OS?  The `c_void_p` could be 4- or 8-bytes depending on the OS, and that will also affect padding of the structure, but I'd only expect the `pInstance` parameter to be affected unless the structure is used in an array.

Comment: Not just the OS, are the pythons both 64 bit?

Comment: Both report the sizeof to be 8 bytes. @MarkTolonen

Comment: Also yes I can say that both versions of python are 64 bit. @tdelaney

Comment: The first structure is much larger than 8 bytes.  5 `int`, a `double` and a pointer.  That's at least 36 bytes assuming 4-byte int, 8-byte double, and 8-byte pointer.  With padding it would be 40 bytes to align the 8-byte pointer correctty.

Comment: @Mark Apologies, the size of 8 was the size of the pointer. If I print the size of it's contents I get 40.

Comment: Do you get that same answer on both implementations?

Comment: @Mark I do indeed!

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you.  Problem must be in code not shown.

Comment: @Mark here's an example of how I use it
    def _status_report(self, prog):
        prog_pointer = prog.contents
        progress_report = {'tab_num': prog_pointer.index,
                           'number_of_stages': prog_pointer.numberOfStages ,
                           'pi': prog_pointer.pInstance,
                           'current_readable_operation': 'temp',
                           'current_percent': prog_pointer.progressPercent, 'current_stage': prog_pointer.currentStage,
                           'current_stage_progress': prog_pointer.currentStageProgress}

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] that includes the code C and Python code so we can reproduce the issue. Edit the question to add code. Don’t put in comments.

Comment: @Mark I've provided the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Some of the structure variables are uninitialized so they are going to be different between two different OSes.  What are your expectations vs. results on the two OSes?

Comment: They were uninitialized honestly due to me forgetting to in the example. I've gone ahead and edited it.

On Windows the values are...well to put it lightly correct. When running on Mac an example set of outputs will be added to the edit.